# Typescript: Class prototyped in index.d.ts gives "x is not a constructor" when trying to use constructor

Tags: typescript, typeerror, es6-modules, type-declaration

I'm trying to use a third party npm module `svgpath` that defines a class `SvgPath`. Type declarations aren't included, so I'm trying to write my own type declarations. They're located in `@types/svgpath/index.d.ts` in my root directory, and I've instructed the ts compiler to use them in `tsconfig.json` with

```
{
  "compilerOptions": 
  {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [ "./@types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

Here's how the class is defined in the module:

```
function SvgPath(path) {
  if (!(this instanceof SvgPath)) { return new SvgPath(path); }
  ...
}

// instance member declarations
SvgPath.prototype.toString = function () {
  ...
};
```

This is what the index.d.ts file looks like:

```
declare module "svgpath" {
  export class SvgPath {
    constructor (path: string): SvgPath;

    toString(): string;
    abs(): SvgPath;
    scale(sx: number, sy?: number): SvgPath;
    translate(x: number, y?: number): SvgPath;
    rotate(angle: number, rx?: number, ry?: number): SvgPath;
    ... 
    more instance functions
    ...
  }
}
```

This is the error, what am I doing wrong? It's my first time writing type declarations for a third party library, so please excuse me if this is completely wrong.

```
TypeError: svgpath___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.SvgPath is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript automatically search types in the *@types* folder and in imported *module* folder.

svgpath already has a .d.ts file ([here](https://github.com/fontello/svgpath/blob/master/index.d.ts)) so no need to rewrite :).

svgpath declaration file:

```js
declare module "svgpath" {
  interface SvgPath {
    (path: string): SvgPath;
    new (path: string): SvgPath;
    abs(): SvgPath;
    scale(sx: number, sy?: number): SvgPath;
    translate(x: number, y?: number): SvgPath;
    rotate(angle: number, rx?: number, ry?: number): SvgPath;
    skewX(degrees: number): SvgPath;
    skewY(degrees: number): SvgPath;
    matrix(m: number[]): SvgPath;
    transform(str: string): SvgPath;
    unshort(): SvgPath;
    unarc(): SvgPath;
    toString(): string;
    round(precision: number): SvgPath;
    iterate(iterator: (segment: any[], index: number, x: number, y: number) => void, keepLazyStack?: boolean): SvgPath;
  }

  const svgPath: SvgPath;
  export = svgPath;
}
```